# How can I perform object tracking using noisy images?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

## The problem

Take 50+ of Lena images, add gaussian noise to them to the point that you couldn't say it is Lena. I insist, gaussian *noise*, **not** gaussian blurring.

Now imagine a cropping window randomly moving around Lena's face (like a video camera focused on this part).

Now you have a handful of noisy pictures containing what used to be Lena's face somewhere in the image.

## The question

Now I want to get back the face without knowing it in advance :)

- First I have to identify overlapping parts (i.e. noisy faces here) from the set of images.
- Then I must superimpose the faces.
- And finally, add them to get back her beautiful face.

The problem is that I have no clue of how to do that (cross correlation, perhaps to identify the faces and the shift between them).
I've never had courses in image processing. I just need a reference or an algorithm name.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is "Super resolution". But it's usually done with far less noise, where registration works reliably. If the cropped patches are large enough, you could use gaussian blurring on the patches to reduce noise and make registration more reliable. If the motion is expected to be smooth, you could use a Kalman or particle filter to improve registration.

Comment: Cross-correlation should be able to register the images even in the presence of noise, shouldn't it?

Comment: Being able to put names on things is sometimes enough. Thank you very much, now I've found plenty of references to keep on moving.

Comment: @endolith, Cross correlation is the ML for detection (Registration for that matter). It works very well for high SNR, for low SNR other methods might be better.

Comment: @Drazick could you be more specific? My images have low SNR: cross-correlation is not working.

Comment: This sounds like an open research problem, what does your advisor think about this?

Answer (score 2):

If the noise levels added to each pixel are independent, perhaps blurring the images first and then applying a pairwise cross-correlation could do the job.

Comment: Tried that with median filter and gaussian filter. I even did gaussian filter then sobel filter and tried feature detection as well as cross correlation : no luck.

Comment: Add tv denoising to the list.

Answer (score 2):

first of all as I understand there are two separate problems
1. Piece together Lena's beautiful face in some kind of panorama
2. Denoise the image.

For 1 - the problem you described could be easily solved using cross correlation. For example please see
[Matlab image registration example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-an-image-using-normalized-cross-correlation.html)

For 2- I would use any of several denoising algorithms.
You could look at 
blind deconvolution and also at wavelet denoising ,

Hope it helps,
May your Lean be as beautiful as the real one ,

Comment: This is not working because: 1) the SNR is low in my case 2) In matlab's example, the patch is fully included in the original image 3) The image contains a lot of features which makes it easy. What I want is to rebuild the full image with 100s of noisy patches and I'm looking for methods to do that.

Comment: is the noise applied on each patch separatly? In what you described it is first applied on the image and only than the patches are cut....if it is applied differently on each patch I would try to look at some texture features.such as hog (histogram of gradients)

Comment: The noise is applied separately on each patch "unfortunately". I'll check about hog. Is that related to the Sobel filter? Seems interesting and might be very well adapted. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Okay another idea.. Mabye you should just allow for several matches .. i.e. for each patch find the 3 best correlated patchs. Than try to build a puzzle out of all the patches building upon all possible solutions.